# Parse Push not working on Parse Server Android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, parse-server

I am a newbie on parse server and have been using it with my android app. But I am having trouble with implementing push notifications. I do not know how to get logs so any guidance will be much appreciated! The installation class does not contain any "GCMSenderId" or "deviceToken".

Here is how I set up parse server to implement push notifications.

Parse Sever : 2.2.7

1) Developer Console a) I create a new project using the new console and clicked on the overflow menu --> Project Info and got my project number. b) Then I went to the "Credentials" page and clicked on Create Credentials --> Api Key --> Server Key and left everything default and clicked create. c) I got the key for my project. Let it be "MY_API_KEY".

2) Now I setup my parse server app to use this api key and project number as you can see from the image. [First Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtTJx.png)

3) Now I setup my android app manifest accordingly as you can see from the picture below. [Second Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxPDQ.png)

I also added ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation.saveInBackground();in my app's Application class.

I am trying to send notifications using the parse dashboard

Please provide any help if possible, thanks!

Comment: Not to deter you from what you are doing, but Parse is shutting down. They will be dropping all support and their servers will cease the beginning of next year. A really good replacement for Parse is Firebase and Pushy.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the open source parse server..

Comment: Oh I see. In that case, continue on. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In step 3, did you use and create the correct permissions for GCM?

For instance

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```